# mkdir(): File exists when exporting Excel file on laravel on IIS8

Tags: laravel, iis-8, php-7.2, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to Export an Excel file from laravel using the maatwebsite/Excel package, and everything was working fine locally, but when I wanted to put it on the IIS Server, I get this Error:
[image]

here's the code responsible for the error in my Controller:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->format("d-m-y-h-m-s");
$data1= json_decode( json_encode($data), true);
$export = new ExcelExport((array) $data1);
$file= Excel::store($export,storage_path('app')."\jobshistorie".$date.".xlsx", "local");
```

I gave the permissions of the entire Project Directory to the Server.
I also have the web.config file in public Directory:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I could use all the help i can get, thanks!

Comment: Are you overwriting a file that already exists?

Comment: @namelivia no, i name every file according to the current timestamp returned by Carbon, so no 2 files have the same name

Comment: You could try and change the temp folder in config/excel.php it may be a permissions issue.

Comment: I did Change it to this:
`   'temporary_files' => [
        'local_path'  => storage_path("app/jobsHistorie"),
        'remote_disk' => null,

    ],`
But it's still not working

Answer (score 2):

I guess I am late but you can try clearing the cache as:
*php artisan config:cache*
or
*php artisan config:clear*

Hope it might help.

Comment: This solved my issue as well. But any idea why?